# how to slowdown the output from functions?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

**Is it possible to slow down the output from Azure Functions Runtime in Visual Studio 2019 or VS 2017? Is it possible to save the output to a file?**

[image]

Comment: Do you mean logging/diagnostic output? If yes most libraries have support for that (and, will probably handle much higher logging rates than a GUI).

Comment: yes richard would love it if you could post an example

Comment: It all depends which diagnostic logging library you are using (there is a certain amount built into functions, but it has been a while since I worked on functions so can't recall the details – and the default may be an artefact of the development runtime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `fileLoggingMode` to `always` in `host.json` to get file log in local. The path will be `%temp%\LogFiles\Application\Functions`. Further more information you could refer to this doc: [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging).

And under Function folder it contains `FunctionName` folder and a `Host` folder. `FunctionName` includes the running logs, and the `Host` includes all details log.

[image]

Suppose this is what you want, hope this could help you.